# Lazy Loading in UITableview Sections IPhone

Tags: iphone

I have "n" Arrays with Images and I want to display images correspondingly in "n" sections of tableview using lazy loading concept.I know how to display one array images in table containing one section.Can anyone Help me???
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. please post some code that you write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much do the same thing; but rather than return the number if images as rows in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection and return numberOfSectionsInTableView: as 1  - you turn things around. Have tableView:numberOfRowsInSection return 1 (so one section per image) and numberOfSectionsInTableView: return the number of images.

Your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: code sees the same change; rather than take the index from indexPath.row you take it from indexPath.section.

And that is pretty much it.

Dw.

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [yourImagesArray count];
}
```